# ValueError: non-deterministic detectors while using Stim to simulate Toric code

Tags: programming, stim, toric-code

I am trying to simulate Toric code using `Stim`. Below is my simple circuit specification in `Stim`:

```
QUBIT_COORDS(0, 0) 0
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 0) 1
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 0) 2
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 0) 3
QUBIT_COORDS(0, 1) 4
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 1) 5
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 1) 6
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 1) 7
QUBIT_COORDS(0, 2) 8
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 2) 9
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 2) 10
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 2) 11
QUBIT_COORDS(0, 3) 12
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 3) 13
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 3) 14
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 3) 15
R 1 3 4 6 9 11 12 14 0 2 5 7 8 10 13 15
TICK
DEPOLARIZE1(0.2) 1 3 4 6 9 11 12 14
H 0 2 8 10
TICK
CX 0 12 2 14 8 4 10 6 1 5 3 7 9 13 11 15
TICK
CX 0 3 2 1 8 11 10 9 4 5 6 7 12 13 14 15
TICK
CX 0 4 2 6 8 12 10 14 9 5 11 7 1 13 3 15
TICK
CX 0 1 2 3 8 9 10 11 6 5 4 7 14 13 12 15
TICK
H 0 2 8 10
TICK
MR 0 2 5 7 8 10 13 15
DETECTOR(1, 1, 0) rec[-6]
DETECTOR(3, 1, 0) rec[-5]
DETECTOR(1, 3, 0) rec[-2]
DETECTOR(3, 3, 0) rec[-1]
REPEAT 2 {
    TICK
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.2) 1 3 4 6 9 11 12 14
    H 0 2 8 10
    TICK
    CX 0 12 2 14 8 4 10 6 1 5 3 7 9 13 11 15
    TICK
    CX 0 3 2 1 8 11 10 9 4 5 6 7 12 13 14 15
    TICK
    CX 0 4 2 6 8 12 10 14 9 5 11 7 1 13 3 15
    TICK
    CX 0 1 2 3 8 9 10 11 6 5 4 7 14 13 12 15
    TICK
    H 0 2 8 10
    TICK
    MR 0 2 5 7 8 10 13 15
    SHIFT_COORDS(0, 0, 1)
    DETECTOR(0, 0, 0) rec[-8] rec[-16]
    DETECTOR(2, 0, 0) rec[-7] rec[-15]
    DETECTOR(1, 1, 0) rec[-6] rec[-14]
    DETECTOR(3, 1, 0) rec[-5] rec[-13]
    DETECTOR(0, 2, 0) rec[-4] rec[-12]
    DETECTOR(2, 2, 0) rec[-3] rec[-11]
    DETECTOR(1, 3, 0) rec[-2] rec[-10]
    DETECTOR(3, 3, 0) rec[-1] rec[-9]
    TICK
}
M 1 3 4 6 9 11 12 14
DETECTOR(1, 1, 1) rec[-14] rec[-8] rec[-6] rec[-4] rec[-5]
DETECTOR(3, 1, 1) rec[-13] rec[-7] rec[-5] rec[-3] rec[-6]
DETECTOR(1, 3, 1) rec[-10] rec[-4] rec[-2] rec[-8] rec[-1]
DETECTOR(3, 3, 1) rec[-9] rec[-3] rec[-1] rec[-7] rec[-2]
OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(0) rec[-8] rec[-7]
```

I can not understand why this circuit should contain non-deterministic detectors. Ancilla qubits for measuring $X$-type stabilizers were conjugated with 'Hadamard'. From the circuit construction, there should not be any non-determinism. Can you please help me debug this?

Here is the stack trace when I invoke `detector_error_model`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The circuit contains non-deterministic detectors.
(To allow non-deterministic detectors, use the `allow_gauge_detectors` option.)

This was discovered while analyzing a Z-basis demolition measurement (MR) on:
    qubit 15 [coords (3, 3)]

The collapse anti-commuted with these detectors/observables:
    D13 [coords (2, 0, 2)]
    D16 [coords (0, 2, 2)]

The backward-propagating error sensitivity for D13 was:
    X1 [coords (1, 0)]
    Z2 [coords (2, 0)]
    X3 [coords (3, 0)]
    X5 [coords (1, 1)]
    X6 [coords (2, 1)]
    X14 [coords (2, 3)]
    X15 [coords (3, 3)]

The backward-propagating error sensitivity for D16 was:
    X4 [coords (0, 1)]
    X5 [coords (1, 1)]
    Z8 [coords (0, 2)]
    X9 [coords (1, 2)]
    X11 [coords (3, 2)]
    X12 [coords (0, 3)]
    X15 [coords (3, 3)]

Circuit stack trace:
    during TICK layer #15 of 24
    at instruction #37 [which is a REPEAT 2 block]
    at block's instruction #15 [which is MR 0 2 5 7 8 10 13 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message mentions detector 13 and tick 15. You can make a detslice diagram near there:

```
circuit.diagram(
    "detslice-with-ops-svg",
    tick=range(15, 25),
    filter_coords=["D13"],
)
```

Which will output an SVG image:

[image]

Reading backwards (right to left, bottom to top, because the regions are computed by running backward from the measurements) you can see the stabilizer initially looks reasonable but it has becomes lopside by themiddle-left panel. So the problem is *probably* in the middle panel.

You can also go to [crumble](https://algassert.com/crumble), import the circuit, and track one of the measurement qubit resets forward to see it's not correctly expanding into stabilizers in the next round.

[image]

It's clear there's something wrong with the CNOT layers. If it were me I'd figure it out by editing the circuit in crumble, to get immediate feedback on whether the stabilizers were expanding correctly, then once I knew the correct layers I'd change my generation code.